# mySQL Stored Function to create a slug

Tags: php, mysql, function

Is there a mysql stored function out there to create a slug from a url (or any value really).

So my query can be:

```
SELECT *, SLUG(url) FROM clients
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690432/mysql-query-to-retrieve-full-url-slug

Comment: that works on multiple languages with the help of transliteration.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570865/how-to-rewrite-this-php-slugify-function-to-mysql?noredirect=1#comment49267833_30570865

Answer (score 26):

This is an improved version of Robert Ross's answer.  It is much faster since it avoids looping through all of the allowed characters and just checks by comparing ASCII codes.

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `slugify`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
FUNCTION `slugify`(dirty_string varchar(200))
RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE x, y , z Int;
    Declare temp_string, new_string VarChar(200);
    Declare is_allowed Bool;
    Declare c, check_char VarChar(1);

    set temp_string = LOWER(dirty_string);

    Set temp_string = replace(temp_string, '&', ' and ');

    Select temp_string Regexp('[^a-z0-9\-]+') into x;
    If x = 1 then
        set z = 1;
        While z <= Char_length(temp_string) Do
            Set c = Substring(temp_string, z, 1);
            Set is_allowed = False;
            If !((ascii(c) = 45) or (ascii(c) >= 48 and ascii(c) <= 57) or (ascii(c) >= 97 and ascii(c) <= 122)) Then
                Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, c, '-');
            End If;
            set z = z + 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Select temp_string Regexp("^-|-$|'") into x;
    If x = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "'", '');
        Set z = Char_length(temp_string);
        Set y = Char_length(temp_string);
        Dash_check: While z > 1 Do
            If Strcmp(SubString(temp_string, -1, 1), '-') = 0 Then
                Set temp_string = Substring(temp_string,1, y-1);
                Set y = y - 1;
            Else
                Leave Dash_check;
            End If;
            Set z = z - 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Repeat
        Select temp_string Regexp("--") into x;
        If x = 1 Then
            Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "--", "-");
        End If;
    Until x <> 1 End Repeat;

    If LOCATE('-', temp_string) = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = SUBSTRING(temp_string, 2);
    End If;

    Return temp_string;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a WHOLE lot faster!  Do you happen to have a faster solution to the answer below for checking to see if the slug is unique?

Comment: OMG! Dude, if you were I girl I would marry you! This one is awesome! Well done, really, well done! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very nice.  Be careful though, replacing `&` with ` and ` means that temp_string and the result can be longer than the input string, causing:
```ERROR 1406 (22001) at line nnn: Data too long for column 'temp_string' ```
I worked around this with a folksy 
```replace(temp_string, '&', 'n')```

Answer (score 7):

I took the Slugifier from 
http://nastyhabit.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/mysql-slug-maker-function-aka-the-slugifier/

And modified it to not include "-" in the beginning, (We had "$" as the first character)

Here's my result:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `slugify`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
FUNCTION `slugify`(dirty_string varchar(200))
RETURNS varchar(200) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE x, y , z Int;
    Declare temp_string, allowed_chars, new_string VarChar(200);
    Declare is_allowed Bool;
    Declare c, check_char VarChar(1);

    set allowed_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-";
    set temp_string = dirty_string;

    Select temp_string Regexp('&') Into x;
    If x = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = replace(temp_string, '&', ' and ');
    End If;

    Select temp_string Regexp('[^a-z0-9]+') into x;
    If x = 1 then
        set z = 1;
        While z <= Char_length(temp_string) Do
            Set c = Substring(temp_string, z, 1);
            Set is_allowed = False;
            Set y = 1;
            Inner_Check: While y <= Char_length(allowed_chars) Do
                If (strCmp(ascii(Substring(allowed_chars,y,1)), Ascii(c)) = 0) Then
                    Set is_allowed = True;
                    Leave Inner_Check;
                End If;
                Set y = y + 1;
            End While;
            If is_allowed = False Then
                Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, c, '-');
            End If;

            set z = z + 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Select temp_string Regexp("^-|-$|'") into x;
    If x = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "'", '');
        Set z = Char_length(temp_string);
        Set y = Char_length(temp_string);
        Dash_check: While z > 1 Do
            If Strcmp(SubString(temp_string, -1, 1), '-') = 0 Then
                Set temp_string = Substring(temp_string,1, y-1);
                Set y = y - 1;
            Else
                Leave Dash_check;
            End If;
            Set z = z - 1;
        End While;
    End If;

    Repeat
        Select temp_string Regexp("--") into x;
        If x = 1 Then
            Set temp_string = Replace(temp_string, "--", "-");
        End If;
    Until x <> 1 End Repeat;

    If LOCATE('-', temp_string) = 1 Then
        Set temp_string = SUBSTRING(temp_string, 2);
    End If;

    Return temp_string;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Works well, But! It's pretty slow. If you're trying to select something off of this, you'll add about 1000% of time to the query compared to selecting off a pre-slugged column that's indexed.

Slugged for 500 results was .27 seconds
Non-slugged (through mysql) was .00003 seconds

For inserting data though, this function would work great! Just insert the slugged data into a pre-defined column (THATS INDEXED, since why wouldnt you select something thats slugged?)

Note: The text to be 'slugified' needs to be in lowercase first, as this function does not handle Upper Case letters (converts them to '-').

Comment: Was getting errors with the original - this one worked right out of copy/paste *grin* - thank you

Comment: It removes the first character for me.

Comment: Above function is buggy when two words are passed into it ( New Zealand ) becomes ew-ealand. The function provided by Greg below doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Still slow - an hour and a half to get the slugs for 50,000 rows

Comment: changing set temp_string = dirty_string; to set temp_string = LCASE(dirty_string); was helpful to me

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I would recommend doing this in SQL, but here is a guy that made a function for you called "slugify":

http://nastyhabit.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/mysql-slug-maker-function-aka-the-slugifier/

Comment: I found that and his solution didn't look appealing... maybe I can take some ideas from it.

Why don't you suggest it?

Comment: I think it would be easier to implement on the application layer of things, in PHP in your case.  At least, it would be for me.  I'm no SQL whiz.  For data formatting (which is pretty much what this is), I like to leave that up to the consumer of the data.  You should also do some speed tests, to see which method is more efficient.  I think that will determine which method is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Yea thats what I'm actually doing, trying to find some benchmark numbers and decide from there.

Comment: Maybe the logic is not in PHP or Wordpress  and this is in a mass SQL treatment. It will be awkward to create a PHP line by line routine just for this.

Answer (score 2):

I added some lines to the function Robert posted, in order to make sure the slug is always unique.

This goes right before the end of the function, as you can see below. Make sure you indicate the table name without the brackets [].

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM [table name goes here] WHERE slug LIKE CONCAT('%',temp_string,'%');
    If i > 0 Then
        Set temp_string = CONCAT(temp_string,'-',i+1);
    End If;

    Return temp_string;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented my own slug function supporting accented characters, any contribution to it is welcome.

https://github.com/falcacibar/mysql-routines-collection/blob/master/generate_slug.func.sql

**Feel free to post any suggestions, bugs or any issue or contribution on github or here** but is better github

Comment: What about Russian Alphabet?

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but I don't know too much about the russian alphabet, but you can contribute if you want, you can add the cases =), or you can send me the equivalent characters.

Comment: Of course it not handle all classes, It was created to solve a particular need, are developed to solve latin1 accents. And my point was that you can contribute to handle more cases.

Comment: @FelipeAlcacibar what is the `tr` function in your routine? ahh ok i found it, i was thought it was a gist but it is a repo.

Comment: @ygaradon in the same repo

Comment: hey, nice function, but on my mind 2 problems :
 1. originals "-" are a removed, they have to stay
 2. "'" are remove instead of be replacing by "-"

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code for a long time. Posting here to remember and maybe help someone nowadays

just copy/paste this snippet in your MySQL query tab and run it.

-- suposing your user is root and host is localhost. If not, change root user and localhost value to match yours

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `toSlug`(
    `s` NVARCHAR(500)
)
RETURNS varchar(500) CHARSET utf8
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(s)), 
':', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ',', ''), '\\', ''), '/', ''), '"', ''), '?', ''),
"'", ''), '&', ''), '!', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '-'), '--', '-'), '--', '-'),'ù','u'),
'ú','u'),'û','u'),'ü','u'),'ý','y'),'ë','e'),'à','a'),'á','a'),'â','a'),'ã','a'), 
'ä','a'),'å','a'),'æ','a'),'ç','c'),'è','e'),'é','e'),'ê','e'),'ë','e'),'ì','i'),
'í','i'),'ě','e'), 'š','s'), 'č','c'),'ř','r'), 'ž','z'), 'î','i'),'ï','i'),'ð','o'),
'ñ','n'),'ò','o'),'ó','o'),'ô','o'),'õ','o'),'ö','o'),'ø','o'),'%', '')
```

It will create a function you can call like:

```
UPDATE my_table set my_new_slug_column = toSlug(my_any_column_id_like_to_slug);
```

It will get `my_any_column_id_like_to_slug` value and rewrite/copy to `my_new_slug_column` in table `my_table`

You can also convert a column with text to its slug like:

```
UPDATE my_table set my_column = toSlug(my_column);
```

This case will update my_column itself so e.g. 'Oh my gosh' will be 'oh-my-gosh'

Answer (score 2):

My two cents:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION slugify(str VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE slug, allowed_chars VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE current_char VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE pos, len INT;

    -- Add here custom replaces
    SET slug = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(str)), 'ú', 'u'), 'ç', 'c'), 'ğ', 'g'), ' ', '-'), 'é', 'e'), 'è', 'e'), 'ë', 'e'), 'í', 'i'), 'î', 'i'), 'ò', 'o'), 'õ', 'o'), 'ù', 'u'), 'â', 'a'), 'ã', 'a'), 'ö', 'o'), 'ş', 's'), 'ì', 'i'), 'æ', 'ae'), 'à', 'a'), 'ê', 'e'), 'ñ', 'n'), 'ý', 'y'), 'ô', 'o'), 'û', 'u'), 'ï', 'i'), 'ó', 'o'), 'ü', 'u'), 'á', 'a'), 'å', 'a'), 'ä', 'a'), '_', '-');
    SET pos = 1;
    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(slug);
    SET allowed_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-';

    -- Remove not allowed characters
    WHILE pos <= len DO
        SET current_char = SUBSTRING(slug, pos, 1);
        IF LOCATE(current_char, allowed_chars) = 0 THEN
            SET slug = REPLACE(slug, current_char, '');
        END IF;
        SET pos = pos + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
    -- Squish dashes
    WHILE LOCATE('--', slug) > 0 DO
        SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '--', '-');
    END WHILE;
    
    RETURN slug;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION slug(input_string VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE slug          VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE replace_chars VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿÑñ';
    DECLARE with_chars    VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeCcIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuYyyNn';
    DECLARE i             INT          DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE len           INT;

    -- Remove special characters.
    SET slug = LOWER(input_string);
    SET slug = REGEXP_REPLACE(slug, '[^a-z0-9]+', '-');

    -- Replace accented characters.
    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(replace_chars);

    WHILE i <= len DO
        SET slug = REPLACE(slug, SUBSTRING(replace_chars, i, 1), SUBSTRING(with_chars, i, 1));
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    -- Remove leading and trailing hyphens.
    SET slug = TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM slug);

    RETURN slug;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```