# how to automatically put title in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How does a site like SO put the title of the question dynamically into the url bar.

Is this through rewritemapping and mod rewrite and how can I do it on a normal web host. Thanks

Comment: For various flavors of slug generation routines, see previous SO questions: * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580581/best-way-to-escape-and-create-a-slug
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409831/mysql-stored-function-to-create-a-slug And a few dozen more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903041/how-to-automatically-put-title-in-url
```

the only part that matters is the question ID, `10903041`. So just set up a redirection rule that ignores anything at the end of the URL, much like this:

```
RewriteRule /questions/(\d+) question.php?id=$1
```

The PHP script can then redirect to the correct title if the title is not already provided or is incorrect; much like what happens when you visit [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903041/why-is-this-question-title-so-wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903041/why-is-this-question-title-so-wrong).

Comment: That is a good idea. But if i do a redirect from example.com/1928 to example.com/1928/fish-are-cool will that still gain me search engine juice?

Comment: @yehuda: Yes, just make sure it's a 301.

Comment: how can i do that? Also would i manually have to put hyphens in between the words? Thnx for your help btw

Comment: can you just answer me how to send with header('location: ') function a 301?

Comment: @yehuda: Yes, you would manually put hyphens between words, and I believe a `Location` header should do a 301 for you.

Comment: Cheers. So I dont need to specify another header with a 301 or add it as a parameter to my header function?