# MySQL slug function on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I have a table with a slug field. It's possible to populate automatically this field with a function by manipulation of another field?

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO people('name','slug') VALUES ('xxxx',SLUG(name));
```

Comment: what kind of manipulation are you looking for.

Comment: It's definitely _easier_ to slugify in your choice of server scripting language than [doing it in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8419128/477878).

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL Stored Function to create a slug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409831/mysql-stored-function-to-create-a-slug)

Comment: I want to transform: Ernest Hemingway to ernest-hemingway

Comment: Usually I do it with php, but in this situation I have not a backend and I need to menage db with only Php MyAdmin

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem? Implementing a SLUG function or understanding how to automatically populate a column value based on another when a row is being inserted?

Comment: When I insert a new record: people('name') I want to populate also 'slug' field with a manipulation of 'name'.

Comment: @WalterVilla Did you see the duplicate I linked?

Comment: Yes. But It's a different question. I need use function in INSERT not in SELECT

Comment: @WalterVilla The accepted answer is a slug function though, that works as well for insert as select.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Then sorry. I didn't understand well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE people
(`name` varchar(128), `slug` varchar(128));

-- It's not a real function it's just an oversimplified example
-- you need to implement your own logic     
CREATE FUNCTION NAME_SLUG(name VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
  RETURN LOWER(REPLACE(name, ' ', '-'));

CREATE TRIGGER tg_people_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.slug = NAME_SLUG(NEW.name);

INSERT INTO people (`name`)
VALUES ('Jhon Doe'),('Ian Martin Louis'), ('Mark Lee');

SELECT * FROM people;
```

Output:

```
|             NAME |             SLUG |
---------------------------------------
|         Jhon Doe |         jhon-doe |
| Ian Martin Louis | ian-martin-louis |
|         Mark Lee |         mark-lee |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48d5f/1)** demo

Comment: @WalterVilla You're very welcome. I wasn't sure I got you right but I'm glad I could help :)